# notcontains not working for User objects pulled from AD Groups

Tags: powershell

When using notcontains to check for an object in array it is saying True when it should be false. This is the code that I have.

```
$SPSecUsers = Get-ADGroupMember Test
$AllLondon = Get-ADGroupMember Test_AllLondon
$SPSecUKUsers = @()
$SPSecUSUsers = @()

foreach ($SPSecUser in $SPSecUsers) {
    if ($SPSecUser.distinguishedName -match "DC=uk,DC=company,DC=com") {
        $SPSecUKUsers += $SPSecUser
    } else {
        $SPSecUSUsers += $SPSecUser
    }
}

foreach ($UKUser in $AllLondon) {
    if ($SPSecUKUsers -notcontains $UKUser) {
        Write-Host $UKUser.name -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host $UKUser.name -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Every time I run this, $SPSecUKUsers -notcontains $UKUser brings up True for all users, even when object is in the array.

In debug mode I manually do a check and it still brings up True even though the User object is in the Array.

I have even set both groups to have the exact same users, and it still does not work.

Comment: the `-contains` and `-in` operators [and their `not` versions] require an EXACT MATCH. it's _extremely_ unlikely that you are seeing the same objects, much less the EXACT same objects. try using `$Collection.name` -notcontains $Item.Name` or some variant of that.

Comment: I know it should be an EXACT match, which is confusing because the User accounts are the same account. They are the exact same AD Object. I looked in the debugger at the two objects and there is no difference between the two of them. They have all the same values in the object.

Comment: I have used the .name on the collection and object and that works. Just really odd that comparing the two objects would not work. Thanks Lee_Dailey.

Comment: That's the point. You're comparing two different objects. Even if they represent the same user - they are different.

Comment: @JasonPope - as `olaf` pointed out, the two objects look the same but the array operator in question sees _something_ different. i'm glad to know you got it working! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Don't store the AD user objects *themselves* in your arrays, use their `.SamAccountName` property value instead (generally, pick a property that uniquely identifies the objects):

```sh
# ...
$SPSecUKUsers += $SPSecUser.SamAccountName
# ...
if ($SPSecUKUsers -notcontains $UKUser.SamAccountName) { # ...
```

See the next section, if you want to know why storing the objects themselves doesn't work.

Alternatively - for faster lookups - use a *hashtable*:

```sh
$SPSecUKUsers = @{} # initialize hashtabe
# ...
# Create an entry for the object at hand, using its .SamAccountName
# as the entry *key*; you can store the object itself as the entry *value*.
# If all you need are lookups by SAM account name, however, you can just
# use a fixed value such as $true.
$SPSecUKUsers[$SPSecUser.SamAccountName] = $SPSecUser
# ...
if ($SPSecUKUsers.ContainsKey($UKUser.SamAccountName)) { # ...
```

---

#### About PowerShell's containment (collection-membership) operators:

As Olaf and Lee_Dailey imply in the comments, PowerShell's **[containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) (`-contains` / `notcontains` and `-in` / `-notin`)** check the comparison operand for ***reference equality* (identity)** with the elements of the input array, if those elements are instance of **.NET [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)**, with the exception of `[string]` instances. `[string]` instances and instance of [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) are tested with
***value equality* (equivalence)** - see [Equality Comparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons).

You can think of these operators as an implicit loop over the input array's elements, testing each against the comparison operand with the **`-eq` operator** (or, if you use the case-sensitive variant such as `-ccontains`, with `-ceq`), using reference equality or value equality, depending on the element type.

**Important**: Due to PowerShell's flexible automatic type-conversion rules, which operand is the LHS in an `-eq` operation matters.  **Using `-in` or `-contains` means that the LHS of the implied `-eq` operation is the *array element being tested against***, as the following examples show:

```sh
 # `, 10` creates a single-element array
 '0xa' -in , 10       # equivalent of: 10 -eq '0xa' => $true
 , 10 -contains '0xa' # ditto

 # 
 10 -in , '0xa'        # equivalent of: '0xa' -eq 10 => $false
 , '0xa' -contains 10  # ditto
```

In the first 2 operations, the LHS being a number (`[int]`) forces the string RHS (`[string]`) to a number (`[int]`) too, and the hex "number string" `'0xa'` converts to an `[int]` with decimal value `10` too.

In the latter 2, the LHS being a string (`[string]`) forces the number `10` to become a string too, and `'10'` obviously doesn't match `'0xa'`.

***Value equality* (equivalence) means that two objects have the same *content***, even though, with distinct value-type objects, that content is by definition stored in different memory locations.

Numeric types such as `[int]` and `[double]` are value types, for instance. As a *rough* rule of thumb, objects that *have properties* are often reference types.
You can check a given type's `.IsValueType` property; e.g., `[int].IsValueType` returns `$true`.

***Reference equality* (identity) means that two values are only considered equal if they point to the *very same object in memory*, i.e., the same instance of a reference type.**

Otherwise, they're considered not equal, even if they represent what is *conceptually* the same entity, which is what happened in your case: two separate calls to `Get-ADUser` return *distinct objects*, even if you (in part) ask for the same users in both cases (`Get-ADUser` returns instance of type [`Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduse), which is a reference type).

Examples:

```sh
# Create a custom object...
$customObject = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }
# which is an instance of a reference type.
$customObject.GetType().IsValueType # -> $false

# Create an array comprising a value-type instance (1)
# and a reference-type instance (the custom object).
$arr = 1, $customObject 

# Look for the value-type instance.
$objectToLookFor = 1

$arr -contains $objectToLookFor # value equality -> $true

# Create another custom object, with the same properties as above.
$objectToLookFor = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }

# This lookup *fails*, because $objectToLookFor, despite having the same
# properties as the custom object stored in the array, is a *different object* 
$arr -contains $objectToLookFor # reference equality -> $false(!)

# If we look for the very same object stored in the array, the lookup
# succeeds.
$arr -contains $customObject # -> $true
```