# Powershell Foreach not skipping values from array

Tags: powershell, foreach, skip

I am trying to write a script that downloads web sites information. I am able to download the information but I cannot seem to get the filtering working. I have an a series of values that I want skipped stored in `$TakeOut` but it does not recognize the values in the if `-eq $TakeOut`. I have to write a line for each value.

What I am wondering is, if there is a way to use a `$value` as over time there will be a considerable amount of values to skip.

This works but is not practical in the long run.

```
if ($R.innerText -eq "Home") {Continue}
```

Something like this would be preferable.

```
if ($R.innerText -eq $TakeOut) {Continue}
```

Here is a sample of my code.

```
#List of values to skip
$TakeOut = @()
$TakeOut = (
"Help",
"Home",
"News",
"Sports",
"Terms of use",
"Travel",
"Video",
"Weather"
)

#Retrieve website information
$Results = ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.msn.com/en-ca/").Links)

#Filter and format to new table of values
$objects = @()
foreach($R in $Results) {
   if ($R.innerText -eq $TakeOut) {Continue}
   $objects += New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{'InnerText'= $R.InnerText;'href'=$R.href;'Title'=$R.href.split('/')[4]}
}

#output to file
$objects  | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table -Fragment | Out-String >> $list_F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully use an array as the RHS of an `-eq` operation (the array will be implicitly stringified, which won't work as intended).

**PowerShell has operators `-contains` and `-in` to test membership of a value in an array** (using `-eq` on a per-element basis - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375) for background); therefore:

```
 if ($R.innerText -in $TakeOut) {Continue}
```

---

Generally, your code can be streamlined (PSv3+ syntax):

```
$TakeOut = 
    "Help",
    "Home",
    "News",
    "Sports",
    "Terms of use",
    "Travel",
    "Video",
    "Weather"

#Retrieve website information
$Results = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.msn.com/en-ca/").Links

#Filter and format to new table of values
$objects = foreach($R in $Results) {
   if ($R.innerText -in $TakeOut) {Continue}
   [pscustomobject @{
      InnerText = $R.InnerText
      href = $R.href
      Title = $R.href.split('/')[4]
   }
}

#output to file
$objects | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table -Fragment >> $list_F
```

- Note the absence of `@(...)`, which is never needed for array literals.
- Building an array in a loop with `+=` is slow (and verbose); simply use the `foreach` statement as an expression, which returns the loop body's outputs as an array.
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is PSv3+ syntactic sugar for constructing custom objects; in addition to being faster than a `New-Object` call, it has the added advantage of preserving property order.

You could write the whole thing as a single pipeline:

```
#Retrieve website information
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.msn.com/en-ca/").Links | ForEach-Object {
   #Filter and format to new table of values
   if ($_.innerText -in $TakeOut) {return}
   [pscustomobject @{
      InnerText = $_.InnerText
      href = $_.href
      Title = $_.href.split('/')[4]
   }
} | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table -Fragment >> $list_F
```

Note the need to use `return` instead of `continue` to move on to the next input.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Woody.