# Arrays and -contains - test for substrings in the elements of an array

Tags: powershell, substring, match, contains

I am trying to filter out users that are in a specific group.

I got the following output in a variable:

`Group1
Group2
etc...`

One group for each line saved in an array. Im trying to filter out only one specific group. But when I use `-contains` it always says `$false`, even tho the group is there.

My Code:

```
$group = get-aduser -identity name -properties memberof |
  select-object -expandproperty memberof | %{ (get-adgroup $_).name }

$contains = $group -contains "string"
```

`$contains` is `$false` even if the array has elements that contain the string...

What am I missing?

Comment: It works actually as expected. The only thing you have to take care of ...  "string" has to be an exact match! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like **your misconception was that you expected PowerShell's [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) to perform *substring* matching** against the elements of the LHS array.
Instead, it **performs *equality* tests** - as `-eq` would - against the array's elements - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375) for details.

In order **to perform *literal substring matching* against the *elements of an array***, use the
**[`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator with *escaping*, if needed**:

```
# With non-literal search strings:
[bool] $contains = $group -match ([regex]::Escape($someString))

# With a string literal that doesn't contain regex metachars.,
# escaping isn't needed.
[bool] $contains = $group -match 'foo'

# With a string literal with metachars., you must individually \-escape them.
[bool] $contains = $group -match 'foo\.bar'
```

Note:

- An **alternative** is to use the **[wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based [`-like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like)**, which, however performs *whole-string* matching by default and therefore requires you to enclose the search term in `*...*` for *substring* matching; e.g.:

  ```
  [bool] $contains = $group -like '*foo*'
  ```

  - The following points apply analogously to `-like` too, except that (a) escaping is less likely to be needed, given that only `*`, `?`, `[` / `]` and `` ` `` are metacharacters and (b) character-individual escaping requires `` ` `` and programmatic escaping requires [`[WildcardPattern]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.Escape)
- The above shows a robust, generic way of ensuring that your search string is treated as a *literal* value (verbatim) using [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape), which is necessary because **`-match` expects a *regex* ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)) as its RHS (the search pattern)**.
- Escaping isn't always necessary; specifically, only the presence of so-called metacharacters (those with special meaning in a regex, such as `.`) requires it, and when you're using a string *literal*, you can opt to directly `\`-escape them; e.g., to search for literal substring `a.b`, you can pass `'a\.b'`.

  - Chances are that AD group names do *not* require escaping, but it's important to be aware of the need for it in general.
- As with all operators in PowerShell, by default the matching is case-*insensitive*; use the `-cmatch` variant for case-sensitive matching.
- The **`[bool]` type constraint** above is used to ensure that the result of the `-match` operation is converted to a Boolean:

  - **While `-match` directly returns a Boolean with a *scalar* (non-array) LHS, with an *array* LHS it acts as a *filter*, and returns the *matching array elements* instead**; interpreted in a Boolean context, such as in an `if` conditional, that usually still gives the expected result, because a non-empty array is interpreted as `$true`, whereas an empty one as `$false`; again, however it's important to know the difference.
- This will rarely be a performance concern in practice, but it is worth noting that **`-match`, due to acting as a filter with arrays, always matches against *all* array elements** - it doesn't stop once the *first* match is found, the way that the `-contains` and `-in` operators do.
- On the plus side, you can use `-match` to obtain the matching elements themselves.

---

The mistaken expectation of `-contains` performing *substring* matching may have arisen from **confusion with the similarly named, but unrelated [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) *method***, which indeed performs literal *substring* matching; e.g., `'foo'.Contains('o')` yields `$true`.
Also note that **`.Contains()` is case-*sensitive*** - *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell*, *by default* in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

PowerShell has *no* operator for *literal* substring matching.

However, you could combine PowerShell's generic array-filtering features with the `.Contains()` string method - but note that this will typically perform (potentially much) worse than the `-match` approach.

A reasonably performant alternative is to use the PSv4+ `.Where()` array method as follows:

```
# Note: Substring search is case-sensitive here.
[bool] $contains = $group.Where({ $_.Contains("string") }, 'First')
```

On the plus side, this approach stops matching once the first match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was `-match` insted of `contains`. Now the output is true.