# Renaming files containing square braces

Tags: powershell, square-bracket, rename-item-cmdlet

A PS command for batch renaming of the files in one folder does work for all files in which there is no pair of square brackets but never if the file name contains one. It does work also if one or more right square brackets are in the name, but any number of left brackets cause an error.

The error comment: *rni : Impossible de renommer l'élément situé à l'emplacement « C:\Users\X\documents\dossier\machine[3].txt », car il n'existe pas.*

translation _ rni: impossible to rename the element found in « C:\Users\X\documents\dossier\machine[3].txt », as it does not exist.

Here is the code of the command;

```
$dos1=(ls C:\Users\X\documents\dos1).name
foreach ($fic in $dos1)
{rni C:\Users\X\documents\dos1\$fic §§$fic}
```

User **PetSerAI**'s suggestion to insert "-LiteralPath" works fine for the present case;

```
$dos1=(ls C:\Users\X\documents\dos1).name
foreach ($fic in $dos1)
{rni -literalpath C:\Users\X\documents\dos1\$fic §§$fic}
```

Nevertheless, for a somewhat more complicated code the same problem reccurs; "-LiteralPath" does not have the expected effect in the following code;

```
$dos1=(ls C:\Users\X\documents\dos1).name       
$dos2=(ls C:\Users\X\documents\dos2).name
foreach ($fic2 in $dos2) {foreach ($fic1 in $dos1)
{if ("$fic1" -match "$fic2") {rni -literalpath C:\Users\X\documents\dos1\$fic1 §§$fic1}}}
```

Worse still, renaming occurs for at least one pair of unlike names:

> "**§§§§§§§§machine 5.txt**", "**machine 5.txt**".

Is there a way to make that work without too much additional coding ?

Comment: `rni -LiteralPath`

Comment: Another way to overcome the [feature wildcard and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/supporting-wildcard-characters-in-cmdlet-parameters) is escaping the brackets with (double) backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) has noted, use the `-LiteralPath` parameter to unequivocally pass a path as-is, without the potentially unwanted interpretation as a [*wildcard expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards), because that's what *positional* use of a path argument does, due to implicitly binding to the `-Path` parameter.
- Similarly, you mustn't use `-match` to perform *string-literal* comparisons, as the RHS of `-match` is by design interpreted as a *regex* ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)), where `[...]` has special meaning too, as it does in wildcard expressions (though it's important to note that regexes and wildcards are only distantly related and generally have fundamentally different syntax).

  - To perform string-literal *equality comparison*, simply use `-eq`.
  - In case you need string-literal *substring* matching, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375).

Therefore, use the following:

```
$dos1=(gci -LiteralPath C:\Users\X\documents\dos1).name       
$dos2=(gci -LiteralPath C:\Users\X\documents\dos2).name
foreach ($fic2 in $dos2) {
  foreach ($fic1 in $dos1) {
   if ($fic1 -eq $fic2) { rni -LiteralPath C:\Users\X\documents\dos1\$fic1 §§$fic1 }
  }
}
```

Note: I've replaced `ls` with the more PowerShell-idiomatic alias `gci` for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet (consistent with your use of `rni` for `Rename-Item`); overall, however, it's better to avoid aliases altogether in scripts.

Also note that in PowerShell - unlike in POSIX-like shells such as Bash - there's no need to enclose (string) variables in `"..."`, as referencing them as-is works fine, even if they contain embedded whitespace; that is, if `$var` is a string, use it as-is - no need for `"$var"`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this...

$Files = Get-Childitem -path \\some\path

Foreach  ($file in $Files) {rename-item $file.FullPath -NewName (“something” + $file.Name)

That’s a generic but working version of what you want. The issue is you aren’t actually getting objects, you are getting a list of names.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: The OP's issue is unrelated to whether objects or path strings are used. By using argument `$file.FullPath`  _positionally_, which implies the `-Path` parameter, you're running into the same problem as the OP: the input path is interpreted as a _wildcard pattern_ rather than as a literal path, which won't work as intended with paths that have `[` chars. in them.