# Powershell Rename files if name contains <string>

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to prepend a PatientOrderNumber to the name of files in a directory if the file name includes a unique ID from my CSV file.  I've tried the -like and -contains parameters and have not been successful.

here is my code:

````
$csvPath = "C:\Users\dougadmin28\Desktop\Test\1bs4e.csv"
## Variable to hold path of Files that need to be renamed ##
$filePath = "C:\Users\dougadmin28\Desktop\Node Modify File Name App\pdfs" 

$csv = Import-Csv $csvPath #| Select-Object -Property PatientOrderNumber, FileID, DocumentID, LastName, FirstName|Export-Csv 'C:\Users\dougadmin28\Desktop\Node Modify File Name App\documents.csv'

$files = Get-ChildItem $filePath 


    foreach ($item in $csv){  



            foreach($file in $files)  {     
               if($file.FullName -contains '*$item.DocumentID*') {

                Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName "$($item.PatientOrderNumber+"_"+($item.FileID)+'_'+($item.DocumentID)+'_'+($item.LastName)+'_'+($item.FirstName)+($file.extension))" 

            }#End forEach

        }#End if

    } #End forEach```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Instead of:

```
$file.FullName -contains '*$item.DocumentID*' # WRONG
```

use:

```
$file.FullName -like "*$($item.DocumentID)*"
```

Note the use of `"` instead of `'` and the `$(...)` around the property-access expression.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$file.FullName -contains '*$item.DocumentID*'`

- `-contains` tests *array membership* of the RHS in the array-valued LHS, it doesn't perform substring matching.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375) for the difference between PowerShell's `-contains` operator and the `String.Contains()` .NET method.
- `'...'` strings are taken *literally* (verbatim), so no expansion (interpolation) is performed; `"..."` (expandable strings) must be used for string interpolation.

  - See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for documentation about PowerShell's string-literal types.
- Inside an expandable string, only *simple* variable references (e.g., `$item`) can be embedded as-is; anything more complex, such as an *expression* that involves *property access* (e.g. `$item.DocumentID`), requires enclosing in `$(...)`, the subexpression operator.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of string expansion (interpolation) in PowerShell.