# If instruction doesn't work properly in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have following variable:

[string]$fullAccess = 'add'

and IF instruction:

```
if(($fullAccess -cnotcontains '*add*') -or ($fullAccess -cnotcontains '*remove*')) {
    $fullAccess = Read-Host "Define if you would like to ADD or REMOVE fullAccess for $user user to $mailboxName mailbox"
}else{
    Write-Host 's'
}
```

Even tho my variable contains word add, it still prompts me to enter add or remove.

What's the issue here?

Comment: please, _please_, read the instructions on how the `-contains` and `-in` operators work. **_you are doing it OH-SO-WRONG._** [*grin*]

Comment: I get exactly same result with: 


`if(($fullAccess -notlike '*add*') -or ($fullAccess -notlike '*remove*')) {
        $fullAccess = Read-Host "Define if you would like to ADD or REMOVE fullAccess for $user user to $mailboxName mailbox"
    }`

Comment: .contains may be more of what you’re after. -contains works against arrays.

Comment: @Pogorzela - please take a look at the Answer i posted. it shows one way to get a user choice and how to handle valid/invalid responses. i think that is what you really are aiming at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach:

- Your logic is flawed: because you're using *negated* operators you need `-and` rather than `-or` - otherwise, the condition is *always* `$true`:

  - To give a simplified example with the [`-ne` (non-inequality) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-ne):
    `$val -ne 'a'  -or  $val -ne 'b'` is `$true` irrespective of the value of `$val`:

    - if `$val` is `'a'` it is by definition not `'b'`, so the second condition is `$true`, and therefore the conditional as a whole.
    - if `$val` is `'b'` or any other value, the first condition is `$true`, and therefore the conditional as a whole.
- **PowerShell's [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains) operator and its variants do *not* test a string for *substrings*** - instead, they test the RHS string for *being contained in full* in the LHS *collection*, as the [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in) operator does, only with the operands reversed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375).

By contrast, it is the **[`System.String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains) *.NET method*** that performs literal substring matching (case-*sensitively* by default), so one solution is:

```
$fullAccess = 'add'

if (-not $fullAccess.Contains('add') -and -not $fullAccess.Contains('delete')) {
    $fullAccess = Read-Host "Define if you would like to ADD or REMOVE fullAccess for $user user to $mailboxName mailbox"
} else {
    Write-Host 's'
}
```

You could also a variant of **`-like`**, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like):
`$fullAccess -cnotlike '*add*' -and $fullAccess -cnotlike '*delete*'`

**Alternative formulation with positive operators and `-or`, negated *as a whole* with [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators)**:

`-not ($fullAccess -clike '*add*' -or $fullAccess -clike '*delete*')`

---

Alternatively, and more succinctly, you could use a variant of **`-match`**, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match):

```
$fullAccess = 'add'

if ($fullAccess -cnotmatch 'add|delete') {
    $fullAccess = Read-Host "Define if you would like to ADD or REMOVE fullAccess for $user user to $mailboxName mailbox"
} else {
    Write-Host 's'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code logic is strange. i gave up trying to sort out the glitch and rewrote the "choose one" code. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- initializes the $Vars
- uses a `while $Choice is $Null` block to get the user choice
- shows the question
- gets the user choice
- checks it against the allowed values
- if valid, sets `$FullAccess` to the desired value
- if NOT valid, sets `$Choice` to `$Null`
- displays the final valid value

the code ...

```
$UserName = $env:USERNAME
$MailBoxName = 'SharedMailBox@example.com'
$FullAccess = $Null

$Choice = $Null
while ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Choice))
    {
    Write-Host ('Do you want to (A)dd or (R)emove full access for user [ {0} ] to mailbox [ {1} ] ?' -f $UserName, $MailBoxName)
    $Choice = Read-Host '    Your choice '

    if ($Choice -eq 'a')
        {
        $FullAccess = 'Add'
        }
        elseif ($Choice -eq 'r')
        {
        $FullAccess = 'Remove'
        }
        else
        {
        $Choice = $Null
        }
    }

'$FullAccess = {0}' -f $FullAccess
```

output ...

```
Do you want to (A)dd or (R)emove full access for user [ MyUserName ] to mailbox [ SharedMailBox@example.com ] ?
    Your choice : 3
Do you want to (A)dd or (R)emove full access for user [ MyUserName ] to mailbox [ SharedMailBox@example.com ] ?
    Your choice : t
Do you want to (A)dd or (R)emove full access for user [ MyUserName ] to mailbox [ SharedMailBox@example.com ] ?
    Your choice : wer
Do you want to (A)dd or (R)emove full access for user [ MyUserName ] to mailbox [ SharedMailBox@example.com ] ?
    Your choice : r
$FullAccess = Remove
```