# Compare two arrays and exclude elements they have in common

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

My first array contains line of strings (`$unprotected`, which contains lines such as `"this list contains 456454`"), which needs to be compared with another array (`$blocklist`, e.g. `@('456454', '456789')`.

Here is my attempt:

```bash
foreach ($ele in $blocklist) {
  foreach ($elem in $unprotected) { 
    if ($ele -contains $elem) { } 
    else { $var_chk = '1' }
  }
  if ($var_chk = '1') { $Arr_lst += $elem }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2: replaced the `;` in the array declarations with `,`
Honestly, no idea what the shell was I thinking using `;`

UPDATE:

Use `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instead of regular arrays

```
  $unprotected=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@(88128,6465,1,415,2,30,8)
  $blocklist=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@(1,2,8)
  $blocklist.ForEach( { $unprotected.Remove($_) } )
```

ORIGINAL:

perhaps `Compare-Object`?
it returns an array of `[PSCustomObject]` for every value that is not in both, with the value and an arrow to explicit if it was present in the left or right array

Example:

```
PS > $Comparison = Compare-Object @(1;2;3;4) @(1;2;4;5)

PS > $Comparison | Format-List

     InputObject   : 5
     SideIndicator : =>
     
     InputObject   : 3
     SideIndicator : <=
```

Comment: This is good, but if both the list has exact value, but my first list contains a string, and the loop first find if the string contains any value from the blocklist

Comment: I thought your use of semi-colons in your array construction in your other answer might have been a typo - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579650/3156906 - but it looks like that’s how you prefer to declare them. Note that while that might be a personal preference, it’s not really the idiomatic way to do things and you might be encouraging odd conventions by including them in your answers here. I’d ask that you *consider* using commas when declaring array literals in your answers instead…

Comment: To clarify, ```@( 1; 2; 3)``` is roughly equivalent to ```@( write-output 1; write-output 2; write-output 3)``` whereas ```@( 1, 2, 3)``` is an atomic array declaration…

Comment: @mclayton actually I usually use commas, no idea why I kept writing semicolons in these answers LOL.

Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your *immediate* problem is that **PowerShell's `-contains` operator is a *collection operator*** that tests if the LHS object is *equal in full* to at least one element of the RHS collection. It is **not to be confused with the  `.Contains()` .NET *method* for *substring matching***.

- While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for *literal* substring matching, you can use `-like` with *wildcard expressions* or `-match` with *regular expressions*, both of which are case-*insensitive* by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375) for details.

In your case, I suggest using **a streamlined [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based approach**, using `-notmatch`, the negated form of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator:

- Formulate a single regex with alternation (`|`) that finds any element of your `$blockList` array in a larger input string, as a whole word.
- Then use the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) to iterate over the elements of your `$unprotected` array and return only those elements that do *not* match the regex, via `-notmatch`.

```bash
# With @('456454', '456789') contained in $blockList, this yields:
#    '\b(?:456454|456789)\b'
$regex = '\b(?:{0})\b' -f ($blockList -join '|')

$resultArray = $unprotected.Where({ $_ -notmatch $regex })
```

Comment: Hi Mklement0 - tried that, but it doesn't filter out the enteries from $blocklist

Comment: @Bhupesh, do you mean that the logic looks correct, but isn't working in practice? Can you can give an example of a `$blockList` entry and a `$regex` where filtering doesn't work?

Comment: $blocklist('1234566', '1234567')
$regex = '\b(?:{0})\b' -f ($blockList -join '|')

The result contains the entry of $blocklist

Comment: @Bhupesh What you're showing is the intentional construction of the regex _from all elements of `$blockList`_. The resulting regex is `'\b(?:1234566|1234567)\b'`, and `"this list contains 1234566" -match '\b(?:1234566|1234567)\b'` is `$true`, for instance. Isn't that the intent? If not, please clarify. (I meant to also ask for an example of an `$unprotected` element in my previous comment.)

Comment: Ok, so If I need to store the values in one variable, and then try to put the variable name with the regex, then what could be the command.  Sorry for my short knowledge :-)

I mean
$blocklist('1234566', '1234567')

Comment: @Bhupesh, I don't understand what you're asking, but note that the code in this answer uses the same variable names as in your question. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Bhupesh: Note that `$blocklist('1234566', '1234567')` is invalid syntax. If you simply meant to _assign_ the array to variable `$blocklist`, the correct syntax is: `$blocklist = '1234566', '1234567'` (you may, but needn't use `(...)` or `@(...)` around the elements here).

Comment: @Bhupesh: Perhaps you need help with PowerShell's fundamentals. If so, this site isn't the right place for that. That said, if you can distill your remaining problem into a [mcve], we may be able to help you.