# Any way to change my script so its faster to perform the function?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script that imports a list of computer names, pings each computer from the list to see if its online. If it is online, it requests a few lines of information from the workstation. I run this script once a week, but it takes hours to finish.... It performs the actions on each computer 1 at a time... curious if I could change it to perform the same actions on multiple computers or all of them at the same time.

```
$localComputer = "MyComputerName"
$computer = Import-Csv "\\$localComputer\path\computers.csv"
$outArray = @()

foreach ($computer in $computer) {
    $pingTest = Test-Connection $computer $computer.name -Count 1 -Quiet

    if ($pingTest -eq $false) {
        Write-Host $computer.name -ForgroundColor Red

        $outArray += New-Object PSobject -Property @{
            'computer' = $computer.name
            'ping' = "Offline"
            'model' = "N/A"
            'serviceTag' = "N/A"
            'osVersion' = "N/A"
        }
    
    }
    
    else {
        Write-Host $computer.name -ForegroundColor Green
        Get-Service -ComputerName $computer.name -name winrm | Restart-Service 
        start-sleep -s 1
        $modelInfo = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock {Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem}
        $serviceTag = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock {Get-wmiobject win32_bios}
        $osVersion = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"}

        $outArray += New-Object PSobject -Property @{
            'computer' = $computer.name
            'ping' = "Online"
            'model' = $modelInfo.Model
            'serviceTag' = $serviceTag.SerialNumber
            'osVersion' = $osVersion.DisplayVersion
        }
    
    }
}

$outArray | Select-Object 'computer','serviceTag','model','osVersion','ping' | Export-Csv "\\$localComputer\path\results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What's with the call to `Restart-Service`? Seems a bit invasive for a reporting script :)

Comment: randomly winRM is in a running status.... but fails to let me pull any information from the workstation.... so i just restarted the service to get around it. I tried doing a IF loop... checking if it was running... but it would technically see it as running still, just bugged out... so the IF loop wouldn't work... and i never figured out another way to go about it..

Comment: There are [several simular questions and answers/examples on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+ping+parallel) in a nutshell: use [`Foreach-Object -Parallel`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/), as e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37954004/1701026. As an aside: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt (although it probably doesn't change much for a script that already takes hours).

Answer (score 1):

So, a number of things that might help

- compress

  ```
  $pingTest = Test-Connection $computer $computer.name -Count 1 -Quiet
  if ($pingTest -eq $false) {
  ```

  into `if ($false -eq Test-Connection $computer $computer.name -Count 1 -Quiet ) {`

  **remember**: the comparing value should always be on the left because it decides the type in the comparison. It's a good habit because you never know when it can cause issues, especially when comparing $false, $null and empty values
- Why the `Restart-Service` and the `Start-Sleep`?
- Use a List and `Foreach-Object -Parallel`

  With the `-Parallel` flag, `Foreach-Object` will work on multiple items of the collection(in this case: computers) at the same time.

  Using a List enable you to use the `.Add()` method, which is more efficient than `+=` because it doesn't destroys and recreate the collection but just adds the new element. Especially because I think you don't care about the order the elements get added(if you do, just add a timestamp property so you can order them)

  ```
  PS > $outArray = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::New()

  PS > @(1;2;3) | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
         $temp = $using:outArray # this associates the $outArray variable that exist outside the scope of the Loop with the $temp variable that exists only in each loop independently
         $temp.add([pscustomobject]@{a=$_; b="zio_$_"}) 
     }

  PS > $outVariable

       a  b
       -  -
       1  zio_1
       2  zio_2
       3  zio_3
  ```

Comment: [Many of the techniques described here aren't idiomatic PowerShell and may reduce the readability of a PowerShell script. Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) In this case ( including the example in the question), you might simply use the PowerShell pipeline: `1,2,3 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { [pscustomobject]@{a=$_; b="zio_$_"}) } | Select-Object ... | export-Csv ...` (which also saves memory).

Comment: Your use of ```@(1;2;3)``` is subtly different to an array declaration using commas: ```@(1,2,3)``` - you’re effectively executing 3 *statements* and capturing their results into an array - compare ```{@(1,2,3)}.Ast.Endblock.statements[0].pipelineelements[0].expression.subexpression.statements[0]``` to using your *semi-colon* separated version…

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation on putting the comparison value on the left, im still learning... very new to all of this.. regarding the Restart-Service and start-sleep... this is because i would get random computers that would give remote error trying to run the invoke commands... about winRM service, but when i tried to do a IF loop to detect them, often times they would still show as "running" and still give me winRM errors. So i couldn't figure out another way around the issue outside of just restarting the service...

Comment: So when i restarted the service, i had to put a small 1 second pause, because i ran into issues of the computer restarting the service and the script trying to pull the information before the service was finish restarting, giving me errors.

Comment: So, I tried to use the -Parallel command, but it reports back a parameter error on the -Parallel... looked into it and it said I needed PowerShell Version 7 and the version on my computer was v5.1, so i downloaded and installed Version 7 and I'm still getting the same error. Im going to look into it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like this, doing things in parallel and avoiding any kind of array copying with "+=".  test-connection has some annoying inconsistencies between header names and property names.  At first I was trying a try/catch with invoke-command, but I didn't get it to work.  powershell 5.1 test-connection only.  & { } or $( ) probably work just as well here.

```
$computers = Import-Csv computers.csv | % name

$pingTest = Test-Connection $computers -AsJob -count 1 |
  receive-job -wait -AutoRemoveJob
$up = $pingtest | ? responsetime | % address
$down = $pingtest | ? { -not $_.responsetime } | % address

& { 
  $down | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      pscomputername = $_
      ping = 'Offline'
      model = 'N/A'
      serviceTag = 'N/A'
      osVersion = 'N/A'
    }
  }
  
  invoke-command $up {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      ping = 'Online'
      model = Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | % Model
      serviceTag = Get-wmiobject win32_bios | % SerialNumber
      osVersion =
        Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' |
        % DisplayVersion
    }
  }
} | Export-Csv results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

```
import-csv results.csv | ft

pscomputername ping    model                  serviceTag osVersion
-------------- ----    -----                  ---------- ---------
ar006          Offline N/A                    N/A        N/A
ar002          Online  OptiPlex AIO Plus 7410 4VY5WX3    22H2
ar003          Online  OptiPlex AIO Plus 7410 50V5WX3    22H2
ar001          Online  OptiPlex AIO Plus 7410 GNW5WX3    22H2
```