# search a substring with special characters in a string

Tags: powershell, substring, string-matching

I am searching a substring with special characters in a string. How do I search for the substring in the string.

```
$path = 'c:\test'
$mountpoint = 'c:\test\temp\20190987-120\'
```

I want to search for the `$path` in `$mountpoint`

I have tried using `-match`,`-contains`,`-in` etc..

```
PS C:\>$path = 'c:\test'
PS C:\>$mountpoint = 'c:\test\temp\20190987-120\'
PS C:\>$path -contains $mountpoint
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>[AdminOfThing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652977/45375) is helpful, but I found myself wanting things to be framed differently.</sup>

- You're looking for a way to **perform a *literal substring search* that is *anchored at the start***, which is **only *indirectly* supported in PowerShell** - see the next section for solutions.
- Operators **`-contains` and `-in`** are **unrelated to *substring* matching** (despite the similarity in name between `-contains` and the [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) .NET method).

  - They test a single value's *membership* (being contained *as a whole*) in a *collection*, by way of element-by-element *equality* comparisons (implied `-eq`). See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) and the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375) for details.
  - If you want to *combine* the two tasks - looking for a substring in all elements of a collection - you can take advantage of the fact that PowerShell's `-match` and `-like` operators - discussed below - can operate on *collection*-valued LHSs as well, in which case they act as *filters*; while this is not exactly the same as testing for membership, it can effectively be used for that; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375) shows how to use `-match` that way.

---

#### Solutions:

**Using the .NET framework:**

The .NET **[`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof)** method performs literal substring searching and returns the `0`-based index of the character where the substring starts in the input string (and `-1` if the substring cannot be found at all):

```bash
# -> $true
0 -eq 'foo\bar'.IndexOf('foo\')
```

Note that, unlike PowerShell's operators, the above is case-*sensitive* by default, but you can change to case-insensitive behavior with additional arguments:

```bash
# -> $true
0 -eq 'foo\bar'.IndexOf('FOO\', [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Note that PowerShell uses the *invariant* rather than the current culture in many  (but not all) contexts, such as with operators `-eq`, `-contains`, `-in` and the `switch` statement.

If there were no need to *anchor* your substring search, i.e., if you only want to know whether the substring is contained *somewhere* in the input string, you can use **[`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains)**:

```bash
 # Substring is present, but not at the start
 # Note: matching is case-SENSITIVE.
 # -> $true
 'foo\bar'.Contains('oo\')
```

**Caveat**: In *Windows PowerShell*, `.Contains()` is *invariably* case-*sensitive*. In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, an additional overload is available that offers case-insensitivity (e.g.,
`'FOO\BAR'.Contains('oo\', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')`)

---

**Using the `-match` operator:**

While `-match` does implicitly perform *substring* matching, it does so based on a *regex* ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)) rather than a literal string.

`-match` performs case-*insensitive* matching by default; use the `-cmatch` variant for case-sensitivity.

This means that you can conveniently use `^`, the start-of-input anchor, to ensure that the search expression only matches at the *start* of the input string.

Conversely, in order for your search string to be treated as a *literal* string in your regex, you must `\`-escape any regex *metacharacters* in it (characters that have special meaning) in a regex.

Since `\` is therefore itself a metacharacter, it must be escaped too, namely as `\\`.

In string literals you can do the escaping manually:

```bash
# Manual escaping: \ is doubled.
# Note the ^ to anchor matching at the start.
# -> $true
'foo\bar' -match '^foo\\'
```

Programmatically, when the string as a variable, you must use the [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) method:

```bash
# Programmatic escaping via [regex]::Escape()
# Note the ^ to anchor matching at the start.
# -> $true
$s = 'foo\'; 'foo\bar' -match ('^' + [regex]::Escape($s))
```

---

**Using the `-like` operator:**

Unlike `-match`, `-like` performs *full-string* matching and does so based on [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) (a.k.a *globs* in the Unix world); while distantly related to regexes, they use simpler, incompatible syntax (and are far less powerful).

`-like` performs case-*insensitive* matching by default; use the `-clike` variant for case-sensitivity.

Wildcards have only 3 basic constructs and therefore only 4 metacharacters: `?` (to match a single char.), `*` (to match any number of chars., including none), and `[` (the start of a character set or range matching a single char., e.g., `[a-z]` or `[45]`), and the escape character, `` ` ``

In the simplest case, you can just append `*` to your search string to see if it matches at the start of the input string:

```bash
# OK, because 'foo\' contains none of: ? * [ `
# -> $true
'foo\bar' -like 'foo\*'

# With a variable, using an expandable string:
# -> $true
$s = 'foo\'; 'foo\bar' -like "$s*"
```

As with `-match`, however, programmatic escaping may be necessary, which requires a call to [`[WildcardPattern]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.Escape):

```bash
# -> $true
$s = 'foo['; 'foo[bar' -like ([WildcardPattern]::Escape($s) + '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-Match` in this particular case.

```
$mountpoint -match [regex]::escape($path)
```

The issue here is with the `\` character. It is a special character in a regex pattern and needs to be escaped. Since the `-Match` operator does regex matching, the special characters need to be considered. I chose to use the `Escape()` method for this scenario. You can escape characters individually with the `\` character like `c:\\test`. [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) comments reiterate this idea.

With Regex matching, you have some control over how much matching you want to do. You can include anchors and other special characters to tailor your match. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is one of many online options to test and learn about regex.

If you notice in the example below, the match returns True. This is because the string `c:\test` exists in `c:\testing`, which may give you unwanted results. You need to carefully consider those situations.

```
"c:\testing" -match [regex]::Escape("c:\test")
True
```

`-Contains` and `-in` are containment operators. Their purpose is to check if a single object value exists within a collection of object values. For example, these are best used when you want to compare a single string like `'c:\test'` to a collection like `'c:\test','c:\folder','c:\folder\test'`. They take the value you are testing and basically perform an `-eq` comparison (not literally but more efficiently) against each item in the collection. However, you can compare collections, but that entire test collection must exist as a element in the reference collection. With `-Contains` you want your reference collection to be on the LHS of the operator. With `-in`, you want your reference collection to be on the RHS of the operator.

**Examples Using -Contains and -In**

```
$collection = 'c:\test','c:\folder','c:\folder\test'
$path = 'c:\test'

$collection -contains $path
True

$path -in $collection
True

"c:\test\" -in $collection
False
```

Notice the False return in the last example because the trailing `\` character makes this different from any element in the collection.

Please see [About_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) for information about `-Match` and see [Regex.Escape Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more details on the `Escape()` method.