Run PowerShell script with combinations of parameters
I need help with the code below:
The main goal is to run a verification script on each one of the patches ($Patches)
Currently, each interaction of a patch is using the corresponding user from ($users)
The $patches[$i], $users[$j] is only for my index test
The result for this case is:
2092541 AutomationUser1
2109086 AutomationUser2
2109897 AutomationUser3

$path = "\\myscripts\test" (for example)
[Array]$users = "AutomationUser1","AutomationUser2","AutomationUser3","AutomationUser4","AutomationUser5"
[Array]$patches = "2092541", "2109086", "2109897"

if ($patches) {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $patches.Count; $i++) {

        for ($j = $i ; $j -lt $users.Count; $j++) {
            . C:\AutomaticScript\ScriptForPipelineheader.ps1 -path "$($path)\$($patches[$i])" -User $users[$j]
            #$Tag = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patches[$i] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Fields.'System.Tags'
            Write-Host "$($patches[$i]) $($users[$j])" 
            break
            }
        }
}

But this is not the logic I need, what I need is not to check if a TAG contains a specific string, the check is running after the script and only if the TAG includes it, the next iteration with the next step will use the next user, otherwise (TAG was not found) the patch should run the current user.
For an example:
The script runs on the first patch (2092541), in case the tag is found (run with AutomationUser1) the next patch (2109086) will run with AutomationUser2.
2092541
AutomationUser1
2109086
AutomationUser2

Example 2:
The script runs on the first patch (2092541), in case the tag was not found (run with AutomationUser1) the next patch (2109086) will run with AutomationUser1 also.
2092541
AutomationUser1
2109086
AutomationUser1

Example 3:
The script runs on the first patch (2092541), in case the tag was not found (run with AutomationUser1) the next patch (2109086) will run with AutomationUser1 also. In  case (2109086) has the tag the result should be:
2092541
AutomationUser1
2109086
AutomationUser1
2109897
AutomationUser2

Regarding how to find the tag I am using this: (It's working)
$Tag = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patches[$i] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Fields.'System.Tags'
if ($Tag -contains "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {...}

Just need to add it to the script in the right place and probably use flags
I have tied this and its very close:
if ($patches) {
    $tagfound = 'true'
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $patches.Count; $i++) {      
        for ($j = $i ; $j -lt $users.Count; $j++) {
            if ($tagfound -eq 'false') {
                $j = $j-1
            }
            
            . C:\AutomaticScript\ScriptForPipelineheader.ps1 -path "$($path)\$($patches[$i])" -User $users[$j]
            Write-Host "$($patches[$i]) $($users[$j])" 
            
            $Tag = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patches[$i] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Fields.'System.Tags'
            if ($Tag -contains "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {
                $tagfound = 'true'
            }
            break           
        }
        if ($Tag -notcontains "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {
            $tagfound = 'false'       
        }
    }
}

These are the results:
2092541 AutomationUser1
2109086 AutomationUser1
2092542 AutomationUser2

I am expecting to:
2092541 AutomationUser1
2109086 AutomationUser1
2092542 AutomationUser1

Another option (what do you think?)
if ($patches) {
        $tagfound = 'true'
        $counter = 0
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $patches.Count; $i++) {      
            for ($j = $i ; $j -lt $users.Count; $j++) {
                if ($tagfound -eq 'false') {
                    $j = $j-$counter
                }
                
                . C:\AutomaticScript\ScriptForPipelineheader.ps1 -path "$($path)\$($patches[$i])" -User $users[$j]
                Write-Host "$($patches[$i]) $($users[$j])" 
                
                $Tag = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patches[$i] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Fields.'System.Tags'
                if ($Tag -contains "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {
                    $tagfound = 'true'
                }
                break           
            }
            if ($Tag -notcontains "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {
                $tagfound = 'false'
                $counter += 1        
            }
        }
    }

Or
if ($patches) {
            $counter = 0
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $patches.Count; $i++) {      
                for ($j = $i ; $j -lt $users.Count; $j++) {
                    
                        $j = $j-$counter
  
                    . C:\AutomaticScript\ScriptForPipelineheader.ps1 -path "$($path)\$($patches[$i])" -User $users[$j]
                    Write-Host "$($patches[$i]) $($users[$j])" 
                    
                    $Tag = (Get-VSTeamWorkItem -Id $patches[$i] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Fields.'System.Tags'
                    break           
                }
                if ($Tag -notmatch "#EE_PatchVerificationScriptPassed") {
                    $counter += 1        
                }
            }
        }


The $path variable does not appear to be set. It is not clear how a 'TAG` integrates with the initial code?

It’s very clear.  The tag here is not the issue, you can search a number in a patch like 1, the logic should be if you find something you like in the patch the next patch should work with the second user and if not so with the current user

There is a$path (just not mentioned)

I replaced it with -match because it can be an array. but this is not the issue here.  can you see my last code? I think it is working. the question is about the logic and not about the tag

In my case, after I get the values from TFS only -nomatch is working...
but I do not understand how all the questions here about the tag. I asked about the logic that I think is working in my last code. please do not refer to the tag!!! only for the logic for the patch and the corresponding user. Thanks

Do you yust want to maintain, the as long as its not in the tag, or do you want to make sure that each user patch comination is run without repetition?

This is what the tag holds: PI 18|not done|Dependency on another internal feature; PI 22 candidate
When I do $Tag.GetType(), I get this: System.Object
This return false ($tag -Contains "PI 18")
This return true ($tag.Contains("PI 18"))
This return true ($tag -match "PI 18")

The ; split between the tags

What the different between them
$tag.Contains("PI 18")
$tag -Contains "PI 18"

-contains / -notcontains are collection operators: they test if the LHS object is equal in full to at least one element of the RHS collection. They are not to be confused with the  .Contains() .NET method for substring matching. While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for literal substring matching, you can use -like with wildcard expressions or -match with regular expressions, both of which are case-insensitive by default.

For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654837/45375
