# Powershell check if variable in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, string-comparison

I have a PS script, which loops through file folders and archive some of them:

```
$CSV = import-csv -path C:\folder\Builds\ApplicationsMappingNew.csv
$Application = $CSV.Application

$GetAppPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationDir\Server\*

foreach($line in $GetAppPath){

        $AppPath = $Line.fullname
        $AppName = Split-Path $AppPath -Leaf
        $RAR_Destination = "C:\folder\Builds\test1\SOA-ConfigurationManagement"+"\"+"$AppName"+"_st-FTP.rar"
        Push-Location $AppPath
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\rar" a -r $RAR_Destination 
}
```

And I have a CSV file, which has an Application column:

[image]

My question is - how, inside a `foreach` loop, can I compare the `$Appname` loop variable value with the values inside the `$Application` array variable?

And, if the value of `$AppName` equals a value inside the `$Application` array, execute `Push-Location` and execute a `winrar` command. If not, skip to next element in `foreach($line in $GetAppPath)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question as asked:

> if the value of `$AppName` equals a value inside the `$Application` array

Use either of the following tests:

```bsh
if ($AppName -in $Application) { ...
```

```bsh
if ($Application -contains $AppName) { ...
```

The above performs literal, whole-value, case-insensitive matching to see if `$AppName` is contained in (matches an element of) array `$Application` - see the bottom section for details.

---

Based on [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994524/45375), what you actually needed was not *equality* comparison, but ***wildcard* matching**.

You *can* **use the `-like` operator**, because - like many PowerShell comparison operators, it can operate on *arrays* (collections):

```
if ($Application -like "$AppName*") { ... }
```

Note that this works slightly differently, in that **`-like` with an array-valued LHS doesn't return a *Boolean*, but acts as an *array* filter**; that is, it returns an *array of matching elements*; if nothing matches, you get an *empty* array.

Thanks to PowerShell's [implicit to-Boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375), however, the returned array can be treated like a Boolean, so the conditional is effectively `$false` if nothing matches (empty array), and `$true` if at least one element matched (non-empty array with nonempty strings).

---

#### PowerShell's containment operators, `-in` and `-contains`:

PowerShell offers two (collection) [containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators):

- `<potential-member> -in <collection>` (the negation exists too: `-notin`)
- `<collection> -contains <potential-member>` (the negation exists too: `-notcontains`)

Both essentially perform an `-eq` test of `<potential-member>` agains each element of `<collection>` and return a Boolean (`$true` or `$false`) to indicate if (at least) one element of the collection matches the potential member.

For strings, as with `-eq`, each element is tested against the potential member using literal, whole-value, case-insensitive matching.

For more information about these operators, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Using @mklement0 hint, I've assembled following solution:

```
$CSV = import-csv -path C:\test\ApplicationsMappingNew.csv
$Application = $CSV.Application
$GetAppPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationDir\Server\*

foreach($line in $GetAppPath){

    $AppPath = $Line.fullname
    $AppName = Split-Path $AppPath -Leaf
    $Appswitch = "$AppName"+"*"
    $RAR_Destination = "C:\folder\Builds\test1\SOA-ConfigurationManagement"+"\"+"$AppName"+"_st-FTP.rar"
    switch ($Appswitch) {$Application -like $_} { 
        Push-Location $AppPath
        &"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\rar" a -r $RAR_Destination 
        } 
        default {Write-Host "Application $AppName is not in csv file."}
}
```

Comment: That is a little convoluted. You could use `switch ($Application) -Wildcard { $Appswitch { ... } }`, but note that simply using `if ($Application -like $Appswitch) { ... }` is sufficient in your case.