# Powershell problem with service status searching

Tags: windows, powershell, service, properties, status

Hi guys its maybe a easy question for you but im newbie from powershell so can you pls help me?

In school I got an assignment where I needed to make a menu, a script that could search from service to status, and a script that could search from status to service, and it looks like this:

```
    elseif ($menu -eq "2") {
    $statusbank = (Get-Service).Status
    $sstatuss = Read-Host "Bitte geben Sie ein Status ein z.B Running/Stopped"

if ($statusbank.Contains([string]$sstatuss)) {
        $Information = (Get-Service | Where-Object {$_status -eq $sstatuss}).Name | format-list -property Name
        Write-Host  $Information
    }
}
```

i really dont understand where my problem is.
It dosn't work: It doesn't do anything and then just ends the script
If i debug, i only see it will skip this, even they are a lot of true value in $statusbank :

> if ($statusbank.Contains([string]$sstatuss)) {

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: yeah it dosn't work

Comment: Yeah, we can't see your screen hence we're unable to understand what the problem may be.

Comment: yeah sry mb, now i has edited it

Comment: `.Contains()` is the **string** method to test if a string contains another substring. Use the `-contains`operator instead, which tests if an **array** contains a certain substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
elseif ($menu -eq "2")
{
    $statusbank = Get-Service
    $sstatuss = Read-Host "Bitte geben Sie ein Status ein z.B Running/Stopped"

    if($sstatuss -match '^(Running|Stopped)$' -and $sstatuss -in $statusbank.Status)
    {
        $statusbank | Where-Object Status -EQ $sstatuss |
        Format-Table -Property Name,Status
    }
}
```

Comment: @kaiwenShao yup, no problem :) `.Contains(...)` wouldn't work on the Service's Status array that's why I used `-in` instead. If this answer was helpful to you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394945/45375) with an *optimization*:

```sh
# Prompt until a valid service status identifier is entered.
do {
  try {
    [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus] $sStatus = 
      Read-Host "Please specify the desired service status (e.g., Running or Stopped)"
    break # A valid value was entered, exit the loop
  } catch { }
  Write-Warning "Unknown status; please specify one of: $([Enum]::GetNames([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]))"
} while ($true)

# Now output the names of all services that are in the specified state, if any:
(Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq $sStatus).Name
```

Casting the user input (which is always a *string*) to type [`[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus) (the type of the `.Status` property of the objects returned by [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Service)) is used to ensure that a valid service-status identifier was entered.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Leaving the inefficiency of calling `Get-Service` twice aside, **your primary problem was the use of the `.Contains()` .NET array *method*** (implemented via the [`IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList.Contains)):

- `.Contains()` performs no on-demand type conversions, so looking for a *string* (`$sstatuss`) in your array of *`[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]`* values (`$statusbank`) never succeeds.
- By contrast, PowerShell's [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) *operator* *does* perform on-demand type conversions (as PowerShell generally does) and is notably also case-*insensitive* (as PowerShell generally is). The same applies to functionally equivalent, but operands-reversed [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin).

To illustrate the difference:

```sh
# Sample array with [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus] elements.
$array = [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running,
         [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped

# WRONG.
$array.Contains('running') # !! always $false with a [string] as input

# OK.
$array -contains 'running' # -> $true - on-demand type conversion
                           # from string to [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]
```

In a nutshell: `-contains` is in effect using the [`-eq` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) against each element behind the scenes, so the latter's automatic type conversions and case-insensitivity apply. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375) for more information about `-contains` and `-in`.

Pitfall: Due to having the same name, there's potential for confusion with the [`.Contains()` *string* method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains), which functions differently, however: it performs *literal substring* matching, and there is *no* direct operator equivalent in PowerShell for that  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55597033/45375).

Also:

- `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.
- [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Comment: Wow thank you so much, the tutorial is really clear and usefull <3

Comment: Glad to hear it, @kaiwenShao; my pleasure.